# Is it possible to edit the inline labels of a contour plot after the inline label values are generated?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, label, contour

Below is an example code to generate a contour plot with an inline label. I would like to know how I can edit the inline label.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

def z_func(x, y):
    """ z = z(x,y) ==> Z = Z(X, Y) """
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    return X, Y, Z

def get_xyz_contour_plot(X, Y, Z, cmap='plasma', ncontours=6, linecolor='white'):
    """ Generates a filled contour plot with inline labels """
    plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap=cmap)
    contours = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, ncontours, colors=linecolor)
    plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=8)
    plt.show()


X, Y, Z = z_func(x, y)
get_xyz_contour_plot(X, Y, Z)
```

The code above generates a [plot that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niYfc.png). If I wanted to add a negative sign to the inline label, I could just apply a negative sign in the example above. But for my actual purpose, I am making a contour plot of the pvalue that is associated with a chi square value. The code is too long to post here (hence the alternative example above), but I minimize the negative pvalue associated with chi square rather than chi square itself (via scipy). As such, my function produces a negative output and the inline label shows a negative sign.

Is it possible to edit the inline label by removing the negative sign after the inline label values have been generated? As an example, how could I add a negative sign to the inline labels in the code above without changing `z_func`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify a `fmt` to the `clabel`, which may be a matplotlib formatter instance. You could use a `FuncFormatter` with a function the just reverses the sign of the value before formatting it.

```
fmt_func = lambda x,pos: "{:1.3f}".format(-x)
fmt = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt_func)

plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=8, fmt=fmt)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

def z_func(x, y):
    """ z = z(x,y) ==> Z = Z(X, Y) """
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    return X, Y, Z

def get_xyz_contour_plot(X, Y, Z, cmap='plasma', ncontours=6, linecolor='white'):
    """ Generates a filled contour plot with inline labels """
    plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap=cmap)
    contours = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, ncontours, colors=linecolor)

    fmt_func = lambda x,pos: "{:1.3f}".format(-x)
    fmt = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt_func)

    plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=8, fmt=fmt)
    plt.show()


X, Y, Z = z_func(x, y)
get_xyz_contour_plot(X, Y, Z)
```

[image]